# How to add ActivityIndicator on Custom TableviewCell's button click?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have problem with my custom tableview cell button click event with load activity indicator on selected cells button.
If you have link or other source then please help me out.
I am new in iOS development.

Comment: used MBProgessbar for that.

Comment: if you have any link then please share it.

Comment: Check this one :https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD if any query then tell me.

Comment: I want to add that indicator on each custom cell of tableview and when i select one of them that indicator will show on that cell.

Comment: means you want it in particular cell or center of the view?can you explain it more?

Comment: yes, i want it in particular cell. whenever any cell button pressed then indicator will start animating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is significantly easier because it doesn't involve any third party stuff (even though MBProgressHUD is a great tool). When I created the cell, I created a UIACtivityIndicatorView and added it as the cell's accessoryView. Later, when a row is pressed, I grab a reference to the cell itself at the appropriate indexPath, and then access its accessoryView property, which is the indicator view. From there you can just tell it to start animating.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

        UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

        cell.accessoryView = activityIndicator;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = _items[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // deselect the row if you want the cell to fade out automatically after tapping
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    // get a reference to the cell that the user tapped
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // get the tapped cell's accessory view and cast it as the activity indicator view
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)cell.accessoryView;

    // tell it to start animating
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
```

This results in the following after tapping the first cell:

[image]

You'll have to change the code a bit depending on when/how you want to stop the activity indicator from spinning, but without have more information from you this is the best info I can provide. You'll likely want to add the indexPath.row integer to the progressView's tag property, but there's a bit more to that. Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

Add a tag to the button that's the indexPath of the row, and do something like:

```
- (void)showProgressViewForButton:(id)sender {
    NSInteger tappedCellIndex = sender.tag;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tappedCellIndex inSection:0];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)cell.accessoryView;

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. It is working..
But i have used button in Custom Cell so on click of that; that row's indicator will show.
Any idea then please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

here is the link for MBProgressHUD:

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD